# Firefox not rendering entire CSS document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

**EDIT**

Problem Solved! For some reason I needed to put the background style before the ms vendor prefixes

---

So I launched my website last night and after sending the link out to some of the guys in chat I found that the background image is not displaying at all in Firefox. The path is correct. I went to Firefox and opened firebug, and it seems that Firefox is completely ignoring an entire section of my CSS document. This is not happening in Safari or Chrome. Here is the chunk that I am having a problem with:

(What is looks like in view page source in Safari and Chrome)

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='./ios7.jpg',
    sizingMethod='scale');

    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='./ios7.jpg',
    sizingMethod='scale')";

    background: url(/images/ios7.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
    webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

(What I see in firebug)

```
#header {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Not only is it ignoring the largest section of this style, but it rearranged the rest of it. I've never seen anything like this. You can view the site at [samrapdev.com](http://www.samrapdev.com)

I've come across a few other strange things Firefox seems to be doing such adding styles I never specified, for example:

```
.mainNav ul li:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

Is changed in firefox to:

```
.mainNav ul li:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Side note, I'm getting a repeated `TypeError: listElm[index] is undefined listElm[index].fadeIn(900);` error in all browsers.

Comment: Yeah I was aware of that error and trying to figure out why it is occurring. Both variables are defined and the function works as expected @j08691

Comment: firefox is just showing you the default styles. you used the `background` shorthand property but only specified `background-color` so firefox filled in the rest of the defaults (shorthand `background` property stands for `image repeat attachment position-x position-y color`).

Comment: Okay thank you I wasn't aware Firefox did that @Ennui

Answer (score 2):

Firebug shows you the *applied* styles after the CSS is parsed, and it reorders the properties for consistency.

CSS has rules which cover unrecognised properties (ignore them) and shorthand properties with optional values left out (set them to defaults).

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='./ios7.jpg',
sizingMethod='scale');
```

Proprietary Microsoftism. Ignored.

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='./ios7.jpg',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

Ditto.

```
webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Invalid. (If it was `-webkit-` then it would be an experimental property for WebKit browsers and should be ignored).

```
moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Invalid. (If it was `-moz-` then it would be an experimental properties for Mozilla browsers. Firefox now supports the property without the prefix so it should still be ignored.)

```
o-background-size: 100% 100%;
```

As `webkit` but for Opera.

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
```

This is an example of the default values being inserted.

Comment: Great answer. I still need to figure out why I'm getting the JavaScript error but this cleared up a lot of questions

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of a script error.When i check it in firebug i am getting the following script error

TypeError: listElm[index] is undefined
listElm[index].fadeIn(900);

fixing this will solve the Background issue.

Comment: I don't see why I'm getting that error. Both variables are defined